# Bash comparing array value to find max

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to find the max in an array of integers in bash. I'm pretty new to bash.
Here is what I have so far...

```
    max="${array[0]}"
    for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++))
    do  
        if [ ${array[$i]} > $max ]
        then
            max="${array[$i]}"

        fi
    done
```

where the array is around 500 positive integers ex. `24 27 13 34 2 104 645 411 1042 38 5 24 120 236 2 33 6`. Currently it is always returning the last integer in my array. Seems like it should be an easy fix, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This test `[ ${array[$i]} > $max ]` is performing a *lexical* comparison, so 99 is greater than 100

You want one of these instead:

```
[[ ${array[$i]} -gt $max ]]   # numeric comparison operator
(( ${array[$i]} > $max ))     # arithmetic evaluation
```

Or, use standard tools which will probably be faster despite having to spawn a couple of extra processes:

```
max=$( printf "%d\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -n | tail -1 )
```

Comment: Sorting is overkill for finding the max, as it is an O(n lg n) operation compared to O(n) to find the max with a loop. Depending on the size of the list, though, you may not notice a difference, or the difference won't be worth worrying about.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating over the index, iterate over the items themselves. More specific to your actual problem, make sure you are doing an arithmetic comparison, not a string comparison.

```
max="${array[0]}"
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    (( i > $max )) && max=$i
done
```